# Simple Date format not recognised

Tags: java, datetime, jackson, simpledateformat, objectmapper

I am on Windows 10 with Java 17 using Simple Date Format.

I am trying to get a date format like `2023-10-12 21:26:16` but instead I get `2023-Oct-12 21:26:16`. The date is inside a Jackson 2.15 ObjectMapper.

This is my code:

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", new Locale("en", "NZ")));
ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage();
...
String jsonMessage =  objectMapper.writeValueAsString(errorMessage.builder()
        .message(mostSpecificCauseMessage)
        .timeStamp(sdf.format(System.currentTimeMillis()))
        .build());
```

What am I missing and how can I get a date with `2023-10-12 ....` vs `2023-Oct-12...`?

Comment: In your code `timestamp` is a `String`, not a `Date`.

Comment: Appears very similar to an SQL "timestamp" "date"!!! You appear to want. SQL has some "types" date, time, timestamp , datetime

Comment: The format for month as `Oct` would be `MMM` (if that's the question), but you really should use `java.time`, instead of the long outdated and error prone `SimpleDateFormat`, `java.util.Date`, etc.

Comment: You have not shown code for `sdf` which can be the cause of the problem you are facing. On a separate note, stay away from error-prone `java.util` date-time API and use the modern `java.time` API.

Comment: If you can avoid using the troublesome and long outdated `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`, you should. Use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). And [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things to consider:

First, your `ErrorMessage` class has a timestamp field, which is either String or StringBuffer, but not a date (because you are setting it via `sdf.format(System.currentTimeMillis())`). Therefore, for this timestamp field the line :

```
objectMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", new Locale("en", "NZ")));
```

does not do essentially anything, since for jackson `timestamp` field is just the `String/StringBuffer`, not a any java date/time api class.

Second - what does `sdf` look like in your case? This is what actually formats passed milliseconds from epoch. If it looks like `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`, then you should get the result that you want. For more detailed explanation you should provide a pattern that is backing the `sdf`.

Comment: I made a silly mistake and missed the code that sets sdf - `private static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss"); ` - once this was corrected i got the format I wanted.  As you pointed out the objectMapper line does nothing.

Comment: Note that if you stick SimpleDateFormat, don't make it static since it's not thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

there may be potential cause in your code which the date column in your json , would be string , not date , so  you can have a  try for  following  code snippet , it could  help you realize issue.

```java
    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    public void test () {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

// Configure the date format with a specific locale
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", new Locale("en", "NZ"));
        objectMapper.setDateFormat(sdf);

// Create an instance of ErrorMessage and set its properties
// ...

// Serialize the ErrorMessage object to a JSON string
        String jsonMessage = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new Date());
        System.out.println(jsonMessage);
    }
```

and this the result

```
"2023-10-12 08:56:57.984+0000"
```